# Change by Val, target as range not being recognized

Tags: excel, function, target, offset, byval

```
Cells(R, DataCol).Resize(, ColumnCount).Copy
Cells(R, DataCol).Offset(RowOffset * (R - StartRow), ColOffset).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Hey all, When I use the above code running from a module, it triggers a change by val written in the worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 15 Then
  Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
  End If
End Sub
```

Now the Cells part of the code is copying a block of four cells to column 12, reaching until column 15, but the change val isn't recognizing the 15th column as having a changed value. However when I change the target column to 11,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 11 Then
   Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
   End If
End Sub
```

the value is changed for the entire block of cells so four target changes are made.

Thanks.

Comment: `Target` can be a multi-cell range, so you need to take that into account in your code.

Comment: @tim Yes it is a multi cell range, how do I take that into account in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to process Target to account for >1 cell in the range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c as Range

For each c in Target.cells
    If c.Column = 11 Then
       c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

or:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng as Range

Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(11))
If not rng is nothing then
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
End If

End Sub
```

Also a good idea to disable events before you update the spreadsheet from your Change sub (otherwise you just re-trigger the event with your update). Use

```
 Application.EnableEvents=False
```

then set back to True when done (don't forget that part!)

Comment: I used the first method "Dim C as range" & it works great. Im trying to understand the mechanism- it seems like when you loop through "for each c" it just rewrites the date to the same cell, instead of writing the date to four separate cells?

Comment: It just skips all the changed cells not in Column 11. In your original code you were checking the value of `Target.Column`: if Target is a multi-cell range then `.Column` just checks the top-left cell of that range and returns only the column for that cell.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I put up another post with the code "If c.Value <> Empty Or c.Value = 0 Then End If" I am trying to add  to ignore any blank cells & 0 value cells. That code I wrote is not working though http://stackoverflow.com/q/17177581/2457533