# Change by val target as range to ignore blank and 0 value cells

Tags: excel, vba, target, byval

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Target.Cells
   **If c.Value <> Empty Or c.Value = 0 Then
   End If**
   If c.Column = 11 Then
   c.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now()
 
 End If
 Next c

End Sub
```

I have the above code working well except I am trying to add the bolded code to ignore any blank cells (could also be the option of ignoring 0 value cells, but not necessary).

Comment: `If Len(c.Value)=0 Or c.Value = 0 Then` Not sure exactly what you want to check for...

Comment: @tim I am trying to ignore blank cells or 0 value cells. Because part of another code is deleting an entirerow and when the code executes it keeps looping through each cell-forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
If c.Value != ""
```

should work for blank cells.

At least it worked [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/594926-skipping-blank-cells-excel-visual-basic-applications.html).

As for ignoring the value 0, couldn't you just change the if clause to `if c.Value > 0`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have your two arguments going in different ways, in that your lumping together `<> Empty` and `=0` in the same test.

At any rate, this makes the change if there's something in the cell besides 0 and, as a bonus, clears the change if it is empty or 0.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each c In Target.Cells
    If c.Column = 11 Then
        If c.Value = "" Or c.Value = 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
        Else
            c.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now()
        End If
    End If
Next c
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, for some reason your code works on my first iteration, but then gets stuck & keeps looping in the "Worksheet_change" sub & doesn't return to my module where I am running my other part of the code.

Comment: D'oh, I forgot to turn off EnableEvents, which means that each change generates another, and on, and on.

Comment: Thanks, but its still having the same issue, it gets stuck in the worksheet_change module

Comment: now its working better I removed the "c.value=0" and it stopped removing any cells such as "1.00, 2.00, 3.00 etc..." but its still getting stuck in the worksheet_change I think it keeps looping through blank cells??

Comment: Try removing the part after two lines **ending** with `Else`. Might not have been what you wanted. I assumed you wanted to clear the values in column J if column K was 0 or blank. If that's not true, remove that code. The `c.value = 0` part should be fine, given your original spec. Also, note that I had a couple of stupid errors, so make sure you're using what's posted now. :)

Comment: hey which part after two lines ending with else? "do you mean the "end if". Well my module code has ".EntireRow.ClearContents" and for some reason when it is interacting with the "worksheet_change" its causing the code to loop through seemingly every cell in the row!

Comment: I'm sorry, I've really messed up in my responses. I meant to say remove `c.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
        Else`